# C++ algorithms to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello so today I've decided to start learning Python. I'm studying c++ in school and programming in c++ for about 1 year, so I thought it'll be a great idea to start writing base algorithms from c++ to python. I want to write the the greatest common divisor in python but it gives me this error:

```
File "d:\proiecte\c++ to python algorithms\cmmdc.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(cmmdc(a,b))
  File "d:\proiecte\c++ to python algorithms\cmmdc.py", line 7, in cmmdc
    return cmmdc(b, a % b)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

here is the code:

```
print ("alorithm to solve gcd from c++ to python! ")

def cmmdc(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return cmmdc(b, a % b)
print ("write the first number: ")
a = input()
print ("write the second number: ")
b = input()
print(cmmdc(a,b))
```

Comment: you probably want to cast your input to int. int(input()) should work

Comment: yepp it worked thank u very much :)

Answer (score 2):

`input()` gives a string. You need to use `a = int(input())` and `b = int(input())`.

Answer (score 2):

what you have done is, you have taken the input of a and b as string type but you are treating them as an integer. So you need to be typecast the string while taking input. Refer to the code below:

```
print ("alorithm to solve gcd from c++ to python! ")

def cmmdc(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return cmmdc(b, a % b)
print ("write the first number: ")
a = int(input())    #type casting the string input into integer.
print ("write the second number: ")
b = int(input())
print(cmmdc(a,b))
```